# NiFi PutFile set filename dosen't working

Tags: apache-nifi

1. Get JSON data through Kafka broker.
2. The data are in the following format and the image data is encoded into Base64.
   e.g)`{"filename":"test.jpg","filedata":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgA....."}`
3. I want to save image data that I received through Kafka as a file.
4. However, it is not working properly.

Below is the order in which I wrote the flow and describes only the key settings.

1. ConsumeKafka_2_0 processor
2. EvaluateJsonPath Processor

   Destination     flowfile-content

   rawbytes        $.filedata
3. EvaluateJsonPath Processor (error : did not have valid JSON Content)

   Destination     flowfile-attribute

   filename        $.filename
4. Base64EncodeContent processor
5. PutFile processor

When the flow is executed, the image file is saved normally, but the file name cannot be set. What should I do?

Do you have any site or examples to refer to?

The site of reference is https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/218015/ingesting-binary-files-like-pdf-jpg-png-to-hbase-w.html

Comment: what you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

according to [PutFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFile/index.html) documentation:

> Reads Attributes `filename`: The filename to use when writing the FlowFile to disk.

you just need to use `UpdateAttribute` processor to set value for `filename` attribute

Comment: Is this process same for PutHDFS as well?

Comment: right. you could read this in documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hadoop-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS/index.html

Answer (score 2):

From question I understood that there is a kafka topic which has filename and base64 encoded file content in json format; You want to consume the kafka topic, decode file content with Base64 to construct an image, and store the image in the filename using PutFile.

I came up with a flow that will achieve this requirement and is self explanatory.

1. ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0 (Consumes {"filename":"test.jpg","filedata":"/9j/4AAQSkZ.."})
2. EvaluateJsonPath
     Destination: flowfile-attribute
     rawtypes: $.filedata
     filename: $.filename
3. ReplaceText (Changing flow file content to encoded image content for next processor)
4. Base64EncodeContent (rawtypes is decoded to image by this processor)
5. UpdateAttribute (File name to store the image is updated here)
6. PutFile

Unable to upload flow template here. Posting key processors screenshot

**EvaluateJSONPath**

[image]

**ReplaceText** - (Note replacement value)

[image]

**UpdateAttribute**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In step #2 you have replaced the flow file content with the value of  $.filedata which is no longer JSON, so you can't use EvaluateJsonPath in step 3 since there is no more JSON.

If you reverse the steps 2 and 3, then you can extract the filename to an attribute and still have the original JSON in the flow file content, then extract the filedata to the content.